# Read and copy specific chunks of text in python

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I have seen several similar questions on SO (copying trigger lines or chunks of definite sizes), but they don't quite fit to what I'm trying to do. I have a very large text file (output from Valgrind) that I'd like to cut down to only the parts I need.

The structure of the file is as follows: they are blocks of lines that start with a title line containing the string `'in loss record'`. I want to trigger only on those title lines that also contain the string `'definitely lost'`, then copy all the lines below until another title line is reached (at which point the decision process is repeated).

How can I implement such a select-and-copy script in Python?

Here's what I've tried so far. It works, but I don't think is the most efficient (or pythonic) way of doing it, and so I'd like to see faster approaches, as the files I'm working with are usually quite large. (This method takes 1.8s for a 290M file)

```
with open("in_file.txt","r") as fin:
with open("out_file.txt","w") as fout:                                                                                                                                     
    lines = fin.read().split("\n")
    i=0
    while i<len(lines):
        if "blocks are definitely lost in loss record" in lines[i]:
            fout.write(lines[i].rstrip()+"\n")
            i+=1
            while i<len(lines) and "loss record" not in lines[i]:
                fout.write(lines[i].rstrip()+"\n")
                i+=1
        i+=1
```

Comment: By writing some code. If you've found similar questions, adapt their answers to your specific circumstances.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My point is that these similar questions resort to things like `for line in f` and `if x in f` etc. which doesn't work here.

Comment: Don't they? Why not? Why don't you give a [mcve] demonstrating precisely how they don't apply?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Using a simple for-loop will allow me to pick out trigger lines, and perhaps I can copy a few lines after those, but then I'll be sent back to the line after the trigger line, which I have already copied - doesn't seem like the most efficient method.

Comment: It's not clear why you think that will happen. Again, give a [mcve]. If you haven't actually tried implementing it, do so.

Comment: @aryamccarthy see edit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe see edit.

Comment: ...they said, producing something that *doesn't* use `for line in f`. If you want it to be efficient, don't read the whole file into a string then split it into a list of strings, *use the file as an iterable of lines*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know that. What I *don't know* is how to implement a proper iterable here.

Comment: By default, Python files are iterables that read line-by-line.

Comment: You don't have to implement it - the file handle *already is one*. Just use `for line in fin:`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right, so having done that, when I find a line I want to copy, how do I copy it and the chunk below, *then skip the whole chunk* for the next iteration of the for loop?

Comment: What do you mean? Unless you explicitly `.seek` somewhere the read pointer will keep moving forward. Please *actually try implementing this*, rather than asking how to solve problems you haven't hit yet.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The comment you apparently just removed about setting flags might actually be an appropriate solution :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try with a regex and using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)

Something similar to:

```
import re, mmap

# create a regex that will define each block of text you want here:
pat=re.compile(r'^([^\n]*?blocks are definitely lost in loss record.*?loss record)', re.S | re.M)
with open(fn, 'r+b') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for i, m in enumerate(pat.finditer(mm)):
        # m is a block that you want.
        print m.group(1)
```

Given you have no input example, that regex certainly does not work -- but you get the idea.

With `mmap` the entire file is treated as a string but not necessarily all in memory so large files can be searched and blocks of it selected in this way.

If your file comfortably fits in memory, you can just read the file and use a regex directly (pseudo Python):

```
with open(fn) as fo: 
    pat=re.compile(r'^([^\n]*?blocks are definitely lost in loss record.*?loss record)', re.S | re.M)
    for i, block in pat.finditer(of.read()):
         # deal with each block
```

If you want a line by line non regex approach, read the file line by line (assuming it is a `\n` delimited text file):

```
 with open(fn) as fo: 
     for line in fo: 
         # deal with each line here 

         # DON'T do something like string=fo.read() and 
         # then iterate over the lines of the string please...
         # unless you need random access to the lines out of order
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use `groupby` to identify header lines and set functions that will either write or ignore following lines. Then you can iterate the file line by line and reduce your memory footprint.

```
import itertools

def megs(val):
    return val * (2**20)

def ignorelines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        pass

# assuming ascii or utf-8 you save a small amount of processing by avoiding decode/encode
# and a few fewer trips to the disk with larger buffers
with    open('test.log', 'rb', buffering=megs(4)) as infile,\
        open('out.log', 'wb', buffering=megs(4)) as outfile:
    dump_fctn = ignorelines # ignore lines til we see a good header
    # group by header or contained lines
    for is_hdr, block in itertools.groupby(infile, lambda x: b'in loss record' in x):
        if is_hdr:
            for hdr in block:
                if b'definitely lost' in hdr:
                    outfile.write(hdr)
                    dump_fctn = outfile.writelines
                else:
                    dump_fctn = ignorelines
        else:
            # either writelines or ignorelines, depending on last header seen
            dump_fctn(block)

print(open('out.log').read())
```